# Open .mp4 files in Adobe Media Encoder through a batch file

Tags: ffmpeg, video, powershell, batch, encoding

I would like to create a .bat or PowerShell script that loads all the .mp4 files from the folder where the script is in Adobe Media Encoder, the aim is to facilitate the day-to-day workflow.

I built this script here:

```
start "" "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\FFmpeg_Batch_AV_Converter_Portable_2.8.3_x64\FFBatch.exe" -f "%~dp0\"
```

It works perfectly for most software, as in the example I'm using FFmpeg Batch Converter, but in Adobe Media Encoder I couldn't make it load.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need to double up the % if you use it in a batch file.

Comment: AME does not support any command line arguments directly that isn't passing the application a script. The best way to do this is to open the app, create a "watch folder" and configure the automatic settings from there. When you open the app, every item in the watch folder(s) will be processed accordingly, automatically. If you want to get into making a script for it, you can use the `--console` flag and pass in a script that automates the encoding similar to ffmpeg here: https://ame-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/guide/index.html

Comment: @Narzard Please make an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AME does not support any command line arguments directly that isn't passing the application a script. The best way to do this is to open the app, create a "watch folder" and configure the automatic settings from there. When you open the app, every item in the watch folder(s) will be processed accordingly, automatically. If you want to get into making a script for it, you can use the `--console` flag and pass in a script that automates the encoding similar to ffmpeg here: [ame-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/guide/index.html](https://ame-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/guide/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will study a little more and try to create a script. I don't think watch folders are such a good solution, as I would like the source and output folder to always be variable. For example, if I leave a .bat in my template folder, every time I run it I would like AME to take all the files from that folder and render the proxy and the output of the files be inside a folder called "Proxy" inside from the source folder.
Watch folders help, but they don't prevent the constant rework of moving files around, so I believe that only a script can improve this workflow